# "Seen" status is earlier than the user's last post

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow, profile-page, dates

I posted what I think is a clever answer to:

[Excel Match Bug in a sparse range with duplicate keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362754/excel-match-bug-in-a-sparse-range-with-duplicate-keys/2581233)

But then I noticed the question was posted a while ago on Mar 2.

I wanted to see what the chance of the user logging back in and seeing my answer, but the [OP's profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205347/dangermouse) says the user was seen on Feb 19.

I thought this was supposed to be the date they last logged in? How could they have asked a question on Mar 2 if they haven't logged in since February?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This user was merged with another user, which changed the dates.

Comment: Then shouldn't the seen date become the max seen date of the two merged users?

Answer (score 0):

Magic. Or maybe SOFU became blind and can't see anyone anymore.

Comment: but I'm right to think it is a bug?  I wasn't sure if "Seen" is what I thought it was.