# Times on SO are not always accurate

Tags: support, profile-page

So, I decided to start editing posts and I quickly came across a scenario where the poster asked the question 9 minutes ago but hasn't been seen for 23 minutes. It doesn't affect anything and I assume it's just some sort of queue-based delay in synchronizing but I just wanted to put it here in case it is a bug and not a feature.

Take care.

Comment: What was this question?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Seen" status is earlier than the user's last post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45592/seen-status-is-earlier-than-the-users-last-post)

Comment: The "seen" feature is generally not totally reliable. It's not a general time problem though.

Comment: @Tim that's not an accurate dupe, Ithink -  it was a localized specific issue, while this seems to be describing a general thing. "Seen" is off extremely often, it seems to be a general bug/feature

Comment: I see this all the time - the "seen" time has a 30 minute window and is **not** updated instantly on all actions, included posting.

Comment: @hichris123 - http://stackoverflow.com/q/21272006/3034826

Comment: Thanks everyone. I figured it was nothing. Just wanted to make sure.

Comment: @Pëkka Yeah, I mistook that post for another one. [Timestamp on question is later than Profile's Seen, must be some time traveller or ninja](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70232) is a better candidate. I think there's one where someone explains the specific windowing used (it's 15 minutes), but I can't locate it.