# Posted questions after last seen

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page, last-activity

I've noticed this phenomenon a few times before: find a question that was posted 10 minutes ago, look at the questioner's profile.  Last seen 20 minutes ago.  Does updating last seen happen asynchronously with posting a question?  How long might the lag be?

I'm reluctant to [add this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31690308/why-is-my-custom-uitablecell-not-displaying-the-text), since the phenomenon is probably short lived, but I just noticed it there.  Here are screen images as of this writing...

On the question:

> [image]

In the profile, clicked a second later:

> [image]

Comment: Just noticed this related (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45592/seen-status-is-earlier-than-the-users-last-post?rq=1) but I doubt the cause is the same as the answer given there

Comment: I've noticed this also. I think it's because the "last seen" on the profile page only updates sporadically, and not instantaneously. See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/221414/266359

Comment: I thought I searched thoroughly before posting this, including perusing the suggestions under my new post's title.  Thought this was a novel question, but now see several very pertinent "related" articles.  I guess I need to go to meta-meta to find out why I was only able to find those after posting and whether I should remove this.

Comment: This is actually a very fair bug report. We can't possibly know about this 15 minutes server cache thing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "last seen" date is only updated every *n* minutes, where *n* was 15 the last time I bothered to check.

So when this time is recorded, it won't be updated again for *at least* another 15 minutes, no matter how many times the user accesses the site during this period.

If I post a question 11 minutes after my last access is recorded, stick around for another 3 minutes hitting Ctrl+R as fast as I can, and then stomp off in disgust... You'll see my profile looking similar to what you observed here.

Comment: Okay thanks.  Is the rationale that writing last seen on a question or answer or comment would make those actions too computationally expensive?  I'd be surprised if it added much, marginally.

Comment: The rationale is that this number is tracked to give folks a rough idea of whether a given user is still active; the primary implementation concern is *raw speed*, not accuracy.

Comment: @Shog9 couldn't it just check whenever a user's profile is accessed? Say someone accesses your profile, a query runs that looks up when the last log containing your user id was recorded? That would be accurate I suspect?

Comment: That would add overhead to profile loads, which are already slow.